# Multithreading working perfectly until I hit the com object

Tags: .net, multithreading, com

I'm using com interop to talk to some physical piece of hardware.

When I need the current reading from the hardware I have a nice elaborate piece of threading code that keeps it off my UI thread so that I don't lock up the UI while I query the hardware since sometimes it can take as much as 1-2 minutes (although usually more like 1-5 seconds).

So once I step into the com object it bounces back to the main UI thread and the UI becomes busy during the duration of the reading.

The main app is a .net WPF app, so it STA by default.
The COM object is created on the main thread, but it's created my a singleton factory, so all of these objects are created by the same few lines of UI.

I'd love to show some code, but it's not like the stuff is in just a few lines of code.

What kind of work arounds are there for this behavior?
I'd also love to be able to read from multiple com object simultaneously.

If were to create background threads to spin up these com objects inside my object facotry.  How do I keep them alive to handle the work that gets marshaled back to them?

Comment: Workaround #1: show us some code! You seem to be assuming there's a single specific behavior described by your question, and that someone can tell you how to work around it. You've described about 100 different problems! Post some code so we can see which of the 100 problems you're having.

Comment: Did you create the COM object on the main thread?

Comment: What COM Apartment model is the COM object using, and what Apartment Model is the host using? MTA or STA?

Comment: What is going on in the main thread while this background thread is running?

Comment: Updated question to include the enviroment info. .net WPF main UI thread, wich as far as I can tell is always [STAThread]. The com object is created by the main UI thread and then I'm using a background worker to take the reading.

Comment: Do you have any Sleep's or WaitOne's in the main thread?

Comment: The main thread is UI.

I'm not sure what WPF does while the window is open but the user isnt' interacting.  I'd assume it's some sort of wait state.

Comment: Check that the threads that you start are also STA. iirc MTA is the default here.

Comment: everything I use is either a backgroundworker object or an STA thread, explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it working.

Previously my constructor worked like:

```
internal class Device
{
    private ComDeviceLibrary.UberDevice myDevice;

    internal Device(DeviceInitObject myInitOptions)
    {
        myDevice = new ComDeviceLibrary.UberDevice();
    }
}
```

Now if I do this:

```
internal class Device
{
    private ComDeviceLibrary.UberDevice myDevice;

    internal Device(DeviceInitObject myInitOptions)
    {

        AutoResetEvent createHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        Thread creationThread = new Thread(CreateDevice);
        creationThread.IsBackground = false;
        creationThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.MTA);
        creationThread.Start(createHandle);
        createHandle.WaitOne();
    }

    private void CreateDevice(object objWaitHandle)
    {

        myDevice = new ComDeviceLibrary.UberDevice();
        ((AutoResetEvent)objWaitHandle).Set();
    }
}
```

It works!

Comment: Hmya, what you're doing is highly illegal in the COM apartment threading model.  You might get away with it, just make sure you *never* make a method call on this object from another thread.

Comment: Also if I do this with the apartment model set to STA then it sorta rolls over.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the object is apartment threaded - make sure you call it on the same thread that created it. Otherwise the calls will be routed to the object's home thread via Windows messages, thus blocking the UI.

If everything else fails - spawn a worker process.

EDIT: and another point - the worker thread needs to be an STA, and needs a message loop. Otherwise the object lives in the main thread, with routing and UI blocking.

Comment: I don't think I can even have the worker process accomplish what I need.

Answer (score 0):

"I have a nice elaborate piece of threading code" - This has a 'famous last words' ring to it.

"The COM object is created on the main thread, but it's created my a singleton factory, so all of these objects are created by the same few lines of UI."

If your COM object was created in your GUI thread, why are you surprised when it blocks the GUI thread?  Why not create the COM object in the thread that directly talks to the hardware?

Comment: Well maybe eleborate is the wrong phrase.
I'm suprised because I can create any native .net object and it will either execute the method I call in the background thread or it will throw an exception because it's not on the main thread.

Comment: Do you have a tutorial you can refrence on how to create objects on a seperate thread?

Does that thread stay alive after the object creation has occoured?